# Aggregate a large amount of data using Kafka streams

Tags: apache-kafka, aggregate, apache-kafka-streams

I try to aggregate a large amount of data using time windows of different sizes using Kafka Streams.

I increased the cache size to 2 GB, but when I set the window size in 1 hour I get the CPU load of 100% and the application starts to slow down.

My code looks like this:

```
val tradeStream = builder.stream<String, Trade>(configuration.topicNamePattern, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), JsonSerde(Trade::class.java)))

tradeStream
    .groupBy(
            { _, trade -> trade.pair },
            Serialized.with(JsonSerde(TokensPair::class.java), JsonSerde(Trade::class.java))
    )
    .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(windowDuration).advanceBy(windowHop).until(windowDuration))
    .aggregate(
        { Ticker(windowDuration) },
        { _, newValue, aggregate -> aggregate.add(newValue) },
        Materialized.`as`<TokensPair, Ticker>(storeByPairs)
                .withKeySerde(JsonSerde(TokensPair::class.java))
                .withValueSerde(JsonSerde(Ticker::class.java))
    )
    .toStream()
    .filter { tokensPair, _ -> filterFinishedWindow(tokensPair.window(), windowHop) }
    .map { tokensPair, ticker -> KeyValue(
            TickerKey(ticker.tokensPair!!, windowDuration, Timestamp(tokensPair.window().start())),
            ticker.calcPrice()
    )}
    .to(topicName, Produced.with(JsonSerde(TickerKey::class.java), JsonSerde(Ticker::class.java)))
```

In addition, before sending the aggregated data to the kafka topic they are filtered by end time of the window in order send to topic just finished window.

Perhaps there are some better approaches for implementing this kind of aggregation?

Answer (score 0):

With out a knowing a bit more of the system it’s hard to diagnose.

How many partitions are present in your cluster ?
How many stream applications are you running ?
Are the stream applications running on the same machine ?
Are you using compression for the payload ?
Does it work for smaller intervals?

Hope that helps.